# Как оформить пунктуацию?

Tags: пунктуация

Очень прошу совета по оформлению пунктуации. Как правильно оформит список в этом случае? Или лучше сделать в строчку?

Она будет злить вас подобными фразами:

«Зачем покупать еще одно платье, ты ими все равно их не носишь».

«Ты видела, который час?».

«Поторопись, мы опаздываем».

Answer (score 3):

Можно оформить следующим образом:

Она будет злить вас подобными фразами: «Зачем покупать еще одно платье, ты  все равно их не носишь», (или)«Ты видела, который час?», (или) «Поторопись, мы опаздываем».

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Если части прямой речи включаются в авторское предложение в качестве ряда однородных членов, то они разделяются запятыми при бессоюзной связи или связываются одиночными союзами И, ИЛИ; перед однородным рядом часто находится обобщающее слово, после которого  ставится  двоеточие, например: Мы прочитали надписи на камне: «Навек с тобой», «Здесь были Коля с Катей». Не кричать же нам: «Эй, собака!» или «Эй, кошка!»

Comment: София, спасибо!