# Нужна ли точка после кавычек в приведенном предложении?

Tags: прямая-речь

На празднике было весело, играла музыка, ребята несли плакаты:  «Спорт –  здоровый образ жизни”, « Солнце и вода –  нас закаляют всегда!», «А ты любишь спорт?»

Сравнить:
Дальтоник, он со временем превратился в исключительного мастера карандашного рисунка, и только в последние годы стал писать акварелью — работая на пленэре, спрашивал у прохожих, приводя их этим в полное замешательство: «А какого цвета это здание?» или «А этот цветок, он розовый или синий?»

Оформление двух предложений должно быть одинаковым или разным?

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Здесь уже обсуждался подобный вопрос, но ответ мне НЕ ПОКАЗАЛСЯ ЯСНЫМ И ОДНОЗНАЧНЫМ.

Вообще говоря, правила постановки знаков после кавычек, закрывающих прямую речь, логичны и понятны, если это «одна» прямая речь.  В этом случае  интонация прямой речи  (вопрос, восклицание, понижение тона при повествовании) ПОЛНОСТЬЮ ВОСПРОИЗВОДИТСЯ,  что и видно по знаку.

Если прямая речь ВСТРАИВАЕТСЯ В ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЕ, то ее вопрос/восклицание интонационно не выражается, поэтому окончательным знаком является точка.

А если у нас «две прямые речи», оформленные как ОДНОРОДНЫЕ ЧЛЕНЫ с союзной или  бессоюзной связью?   Будет ли выражаться их интонация, или предложение также закончится повествовательной точкой? Разбирается ли этот вопрос у Лопатина/Розенталя как отдельная тема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Гоголя в "Мертвых душах":

Стол, кресла, стулья - все было самого тяжелого и беспокойного свойства, - словом, каждый предмет, каждый стул, казалось, говорил: "И я тоже Собакевич!" или: "И я тоже очень похож на Собакевича!"

На сайте http://www.slovari.ru/default.aspx?p=1275

Вопрос. В каких случаях ставится точка после закрывающей кавычки, перед которой стоит восклицательный/вопросительный знаки/многоточие? И ставятся ли в следующих случаях двоеточия перед открывающими кавычками? Как звучат правила? Ее жизненный девиз – «..!»(.) В их руках плакаты: «..!», «..!»(.) На двери висела записка: "..!"(.) Девочка пела песенки под возгласы(:) "…!"(.) Ему требовалось ответить только на один вопрос (:) «..?»(.) Держали плакаты с надписью (:) «...!»(.) Он закончил речь фразой (:) «…?»(.) Он встал со словами (:) «...!»(.) Как раз, когда сталкиваешься с подобными случаями, долго сомневаешься. Вы не могли бы дать однозначные рекомендации?

Ответ. Подлинные выражения, вставленные в текст в качестве элементов предложения, выделяются кавычками, но перед ними двоеточие не ставится, например: Это "не хочу" поразило Антона Прокофьевича (в этом примере слова в кавычках пишутся со строчной буквы, так как они выполняют фунцию подлежащего, их легко можно заменить на существительное "слово", "возражение" и др.); Он вспомнил пословицу "Не плюй в колодец..." и отошел в сторону; С криком "Спасайте детей!" юноша бросился в горящее здание. Но если перед подлинным выражением имеются слова предложение, надпись, выражение и т. п., то перед ними ставится двоеточие, например: На двери висела записка: "Ушла на обед". (См.: Д. Э. Розенталь "Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке". М., 2000. C. 169.)
Слова девиза, лозунга, плаката входят обычно в текст как элементы предложения, а не как прямая речь.
Итак, Ваши примеры оформляются так (в скобках после каждого примера обозначено, чем являются слова в кавычках):
Ее жизненный девиз – «..!». (элемент предложения)
В их руках плакаты: «..!», «..!». (элемент предложения)
На двери висела записка: «..!» (прямая речь)
Девочка пела песенки под возгласы: «Замечательно! Хотим еще!» (прямая речь) и Девочка пела песенки под возгласы «Браво!». (элемент предложения)
Ему требовалось ответить только на один вопрос: «..?» (прямая речь)
Держали плакаты с надписью: «..!» (прямая речь)
Он закончил речь фразой: «..?» (прямая речь)
Он встал со словами: «...!» (прямая речь)
Во всех приведенных Вами примерах слова в кавычках будут писаться с прописной буквы.

На сайте [Как оформить пунктуацию?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/34945/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E)
София отвечала на подобный вопрос Очень прошу совета по оформлению пунктуации. Как правильно оформит список в этом случае? Или лучше сделать в строчку?

Она будет злить вас подобными фразами:

«Зачем покупать еще одно платье, ты ими все равно их не носишь».

«Ты видела, который час?».

«Поторопись, мы опаздываем».

отвечала так:

Можно оформить следующим образом:

Она будет злить вас подобными фразами: «Зачем покупать еще одно платье, ты все равно их не носишь», (или)«Ты видела, который час?», (или) «Поторопись, мы опаздываем».

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Если части прямой речи включаются в авторское предложение в качестве ряда однородных членов, то они разделяются запятыми при бессоюзной связи или связываются одиночными союзами И, ИЛИ; перед однородным рядом часто находится обобщающее слово, после которого ставится двоеточие, например: Мы прочитали надписи на камне: «Навек с тобой», «Здесь были Коля с Катей». Не кричать же нам: «Эй, собака!» или «Эй, кошка!»

Конец цитаты.

Правда, у Гоголя после *или* стоит двоеточие.

Стол, кресла, стулья - все было самого тяжелого и беспокойного свойства, - словом, каждый предмет, каждый стул, казалось, говорил: "И я тоже Собакевич!" или: "И я тоже очень похож на Собакевича!"

Я не совсем понимаю, почему после "И я тоже Собакевич!" нет тире. Ведь по современным нормам, если прямая речь заканчивается восклицательным знаком и далее не нужна запятая, то ставится тире. Или это все-таки особый случай?

Comment: Давайте предельно сузим задачу. Итак, у нас две прямые речи после ДВОЕТОЧИЯ, причем это восклицание или вопрос. Так это автор решает  считать их элементами предложения или прямой речью?  Или это уж точно встроенные элементы, точка на конце? А у Гоголя интересный пример, но нестандартно оформленный. Можно переделать: ...каждый стул, казалось, говорил: "И я тоже Собакевич!" или (говорил): "И я тоже очень похож на Собакевича!" Получится две прямые речи внутри слов автора, союз ИЛИ относится к сказуемому.

Answer (score 1):

В первом случае точка нужна, как и в конце любого перечисления.
Во втором случае возможен такой вариант:

... спрашивал у прохожих: «А какого цвета это здание?» Или: «А этот цветок, он розовый или синий?»

Вместо разделения на два предложения здесь, вероятно, можно поставить точку с запятой. Но вряд ли возможно приведение разных вариантов прямой речи после общего двоеточия: это не просто перечисление цитат, а рассказ о поведении персонажа с использованием прямой речи. Каждый случай прямой речи требует отдельного оформления.

Comment: Тогда союз ИЛИ надо убрать и использовать единую прямую речь. "Он спрашивал у прохожих, приводя их этим в полное замешательство: «А какого цвета это здание? А этот цветок, он розовый или синий?»  Но варианты с однородными частями прямой речи реально встречаются:    Мы прочитали надписи на камне:  «Здесь были Коля с Катей», «Навек с тобой!» Не кричать же нам: «Эй, собака!» или «Эй, кошка!»  Как-то без точки на конце эти предложения  не очень смотрятся.