# «Как познать себя?» — с прописной или со строчной?

Tags: пунктуация, прописная-строчная, прямая-речь

Здесь вы найдёте ответы на вопросы: «Как познать себя?», «Как эффективно и здорово жить в современном социуме?»

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Здесь вы найдёте ответы на вопросы: «**К**ак познать себя?», «**К**ак эффективно и здорово жить в современном социуме?».*

Цитата — это дословная выдержка из текста (у Вас — точная формулировка каждого вопроса).

Если цитата включается в текст как самостоятельное предложение, она оформляется так же, как [**прямая речь**](http://www.classes.ru/grammar/127.Rosental-pravopisanie/52.htm):
перед прямой речью, следующей за авторскими словами, ставится двоеточие, причем **первое слово прямой речи пишется с прописной буквы**; вопросительный знак ставится перед закрывающими кавычками, а точка после них.
Т. к. у Вас в предложении два отдельных вопроса, то каждый из них оформляется как отдельная прямая речь; между ними ставится запятая или точка с запятой.
И, конечно, не забываем про точку в самом конце предложения!

*С обеих сторон эту белиберду щедро приправили сомнительные откровения знакомых: «**О**н уже позвонил ей и пригласил на ужин»; «**О**на готовит эксклюзивную домашнюю вечеринку по случаю его прибытия в Лондон»**.***
Р. Гэлбрейт. Зов кукушки

P. S. Предложение можно было оформить и с такой пунктуацией:
Здесь вы найдёте ответы на вопросы: «Как познать себя? Как эффективно и здорово жить в современном социуме?».

Answer (score 0):

В Нацкорпусе можно найти все возможные варианты: с прописной и строчной, с кавычками и без, с двоеточием и без, с вопросительными знаками и без. Очевидно, это объясняется тем, что упомянутые вопросы могут быть представлены не только как цитаты, как прямая речь, но и как их не дословное описание. В газетном варианте — скорее без кавычек:

> «ADIA осознает важность четких ответов на вопросы: что фонд собой представляет, куда инвестирует и почему», — говорится в обзоре фонда. [Евгений Басманов, Владимир Павлов. Абу-Даби решил раскрыться (2010.03.16)]

"Беспроигрышный" вариант:

**Здесь вы найдёте ответы на вопросы том, как познать себя и как эффективно и здорово жить в современном социуме.**

И еще одно замечание. Если вопросов только два, то лучше убрать двоеточие и добавить союз И.

Разные варианты из Нацкорпуса:

> Главное, повторяем, физиология, ответы на вопросы: «Как устроено?» , «Как работает?» , «Почему не работает?» и «Возможно ли поправить поломку в системе?». [С. В. Рязанцев. В мире запахов и звуков (1997)]
>
> ...он отвечает себе на вопросы: «что со мной происходит?» , «что все это значит?» , «что теперь будет?» и «как с этим жить?» [Ольга Балла. Превращение боли в функцию разума // «Знание-сила», 2014]

Comment: Не согласна с оформлением последнего предложения. 1. Местоимение **он** должно быть или с прописной буквы, или необходимо перед ним троеточие. 2. Предложение повествовательное, в конце необходима точка.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова   "Он" - моя вина (я отрезал начало), а точки нет в Нацкорпусе. Если память мне не изменяет, троеточие не избавляет от необходимисти начинать с прописной.

Comment: § 142. Если цитата предшествует авторскому тексту, то после многоточия слово пишется с прописной буквы, если же цитата идет после авторских слов, то после многоточия употребляется строчная буква:  (http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137). У меня, скорее, второй случай, как думаете?

Comment: Это я помню. А где у нас здесь авторский текст?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Можно считать, что "Разные варианты из Нацкорпуса" — это авторский текст, а можно считать, что авторского текста нет совсем.

Comment: Не всегда можно верить Нацкорпусу. Вот как в тексте: **"...он отвечает себе на вопросы, что со мной происходит, что всё это значит, что теперь будет и как с этим жить".** Ссылку дать не получается (попробуйте, наберите сами в Гугле). Автор: Балла-Гертман Ольга Анатольевна.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Похоже, это первоисточник: http://www.phil63.ru/files/010%20vest1-13.pdf, стр. 125 (без кавычек), в Нацкорпусе взято из «Знание-сила», 2014, а здесь с кавычками: http://www.phil63.ru/prevrashchenie-boli-v-funktsiyu-razuma

Comment: Ещё раз повторю, что даже Нацкорпусу не всегда можно верить. Посмотрите, во второй ссылке, представленной Вами (с кавычками), точка в конце предложения присутствует!

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, Нацкорпус взял фразу из «Знание-сила», N1 за 2014. Чтобы делать выводы, нужно увидеть журнал. Мне его найти не удалось. А Вам?

Answer (score 0):

А что если **объединить два вопроса** и получить стандартное оформление прямой речи **без точки в конце**:

**Здесь вы найдёте ответы на вопросы: «Как познать себя? Как эффективно и здорово жить в современном социуме?»**

Такое возможно?

К сожалению, эту тему классики обошли стороной, но в любом случае 
**стандартная прямая речь на части не делится,** и если такое деление присутствует, то мы уже имеем дело **с дополнениями**, содержащими дословные высказывания.

Эта тема обсуждалась на сайте:  [Нужна ли точка после кавычек в приведенном предложении?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/415534/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8/415537)

Comment: Точка не нужна в конце предложения, если интонация авторского предложения тоже вопросительная. Например: **Вы можете ответить на вопросы: «Как познать себя? Как эффективно и здорово жить в современном социуме?»** Вспомните классическое: Как вы ответите на вопрос: "Что делать?" Вопросительные интонации совпадают, "накладываются" - точки нет, второго вопросительного знака нет.

Comment: Но у нас, кажется, не вопросительная интонация, это уже другая тема.  Кстати, про эту точку  в повествовательном авторском предложении мало кто вообще задумывается, если судить по приводимым примерам.

Comment: **Жителям задавались два вопроса: "Кто виноват в войне (...)?" и "Что нужно сделать, чтобы прекратить войну?".** Жителям задавались два вопроса [точка]. Она переносится в конец предложения после закрытия вопроса кавычками.

Comment: Ну да, переносится, должна переноситься. Да вот только выглядит эта точка как-то не на месте, кажется ненужной формальностью, вот ее и не считают нужным ставить.